# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error converting data type nvarchar to date.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I encounter this error as I want to assign the training record. I tried several things, but no progress - can somebody help me to get through this? Appreciate your hard work and very thank you!

This is my code:

```
    protected void ImgBtnDate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if(CalTrain.Visible)
        {
            CalTrain.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            CalTrain.Visible = true;
        }
        CalTrain.Attributes.Add("style", "position:absolute");
    }

    protected void CalTrain_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDate.Text = CalTrain.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        CalTrain.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void CalTrain_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

    }

    protected void lnkEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int TrainID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("TrainViewByID", sqlCon);
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainID", TrainID);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
        sqlCon.Close();
        hfTrainID.Value = TrainID.ToString();
        txtDate.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["TrainDate"].ToString();

        DDLTrainProgram.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["TrainProgram"].ToString();
        DDLTrainTime.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["TrainTime"].ToString();
        DDLTrainVenue.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["TrainVenue"].ToString();
        btnAssign.Text = "Update";
        btnDelete.Enabled = true;
    }


    protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clear();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        hfTrainID.Value = "";
        txtDate.Text = "";
        lblSuccessMessage.Text = lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
        btnAssign.Text = "Assign";
        btnDelete.Enabled = false;
    }

    protected void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("TrainCreateOrUpdate", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainID", (hfTrainID.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(hfTrainID.Value)));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainDate",DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainProgram",DDLTrainProgram.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainTime",DDLTrainTime.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainVenue",DDLTrainVenue.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCon.Close();
        string TrainID = hfTrainID.Value;
        Clear();
        if (TrainID == "")
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Assigned Successfully";
        else
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Updated Successfully";
        FillGVTrain();
    }

    void FillGVTrain()
    {
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("TrainViewAll", sqlCon);
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
        sqlCon.Close();
        gvTrain.DataSource = dtbl;
        gvTrain.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("TrainDeleteByID", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainID", Convert.ToInt32(hfTrainID.Value));
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCon.Close();
        Clear();
        FillGVTrain();
        lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Deleted Successfully";
    }
}
```

Since this is an insert-delete-update function. It cannot insert if I use the code mentioned above. However, if I use the code

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainDate", DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

it can insert successfully but when it comes to edit the details, I have to re-enter the date as it occur another error

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

By the way, the datatype I assigned in SQL Server is `date`.It just cannot run as I thought it will be. I am a newbie to programming as a student. Those codes is from Youtube tutorials.

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dtbl.Rows[0]["TrainDate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime parsedDate))
{
    txtDate.Text = parsedDate;
}
```

But honestly, why don't you use EntityFramework, it saves you time for all of this type hassles.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me. I tried your way but this message `Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'` had come out. Another trouble is the datatype is `date`, but when I insert the record, it turns out datatype `datetime` which the format is `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt` instead of `dd/MM/yyyy`. I am still newbie, I will try to use entity framework.Thanks again